# How to automatically redirect user to a protected page after login with j_security_check

Tags: jsf, jboss7.x, welcome-file

I have a web application developed using JSF1.2 running on JBoss AS7. Except for the login page, all other pages are protected. I also have a custom FormAuthenticator valve that needs to get triggered as part of the authentication processs.

The login page uses `j_security_check`.

My core requirements are:

1. Present the user with the login page when the try to access a protected page (and take the user to the originally requested page after successful login).
2. If the user access the login page directly, take the user to a welcome page after successful login.

Requirement #1 works fine, when I attempt to access `http://server.com/my-app/faces/protected1.jsp`.

However, I get a 404 when attempting to access the web application by its context-root (i.e. `http://server.com/my-app/`).

I tried to use welcome-file attribute in web.xml and my **web.xml** looks as follows:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/faces/protected1.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

...
<!-- login config -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<!-- security constraints -->
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>protected1</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected1</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/protected1.jsp</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>protected1Group</description>
        <role-name>WebUserRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>WebUserRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Am I on the correct track trying to get welcome-file to behave as the default landing page after login (when the user access either the context-root of my app or the login.jsp directly)?
2. Why does the same thing work flawlessly if I change the welcome-file to an unprotected jsp (e.g. `hello.jsp` that has no security constraints)?

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to me to have your welcome file protected. Normally that would be the home page of a site, which anybody should be able to see. Then, if they click on some link to a protected resource such as 'My Stuff', that would take them to /faces/mystuff.something, which would be protected, so there would be a login before they got there.

Comment: The home page in this instance is the login page. So, if I have (1) the home page as the welcome file, (2) the user go directly to the home page (i.e. login page) then I get a "HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page" error because there is no where to be redirected after login.